# How to upload ajax file with codeignitier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

im trying to upload image in codeignitier using ajax 
the problem is in ajax won't send any data to the controller
here is my code:

```js
$("#file-input").change(function(e) {
        $.ajax({   
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ControllerEditor/uploadImageUserAjax",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
    if(data)
    {
     console.log(data);
    }
//            $("#targetLayer").html(data);
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });//end ajax
    }); //end submit
```

```html
<form id="form-uploadImage" action="ControllerEditor/uploadImageUserAjax" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="image-upload">
<label for="file-input">
<img src="asset/globalimage/addIcon.png"/>
</label>
<input id="file-input" name='file-input' type="file"/><br>
Add Image
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code

```
data:  new FormData(this),
```

with the

```
data : new FormData($('#form-uploadImage')[0]),
```

I hope this will help you.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this!hope it's help to you

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" name="formname" id="formname"  method="post" action="">
<div class="image-upload">
<label for="file-input">
<img src="asset/globalimage/addIcon.png"/>
</label>
<input id="file-input" name='file-input' type="file"/><br>
Add Image
</div>
</form>



function uploadImage() {

    if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {

        // send the formData
        var formData = new FormData( $("#formID")[0] );

        $.ajax({
            url : baseUrl + 'uploadImage',  // Controller URL
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                successFunction(data);
            }
        });

    } else {
       message("Your Browser Don't support FormData API! Use IE 10 or Above!");
    }   
}
```